# How can i make one value for one column when using pandas to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am beginner in Deep Learning frameworks,pandas, numpy and python. I am currently training my model using keras backend tensorflow. When i am saving weight values using pandas to csv the result as shown in picture [Pandas to csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRib8.png) . The weight values are in one column. I had checked my weight type and its a list.

How can i save pandas to csv with one value one excel cell?

This is the code that i am using to save pandas to csv

```
weight = model.get_weights()
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
df = pd.DataFrame(weight)
df.to_csv("./Result/w_mlp_p_nodropout_full.csv", index=False)
```

I have tried saving weight with numpy to txt and convert txt to csv and it had succeeded.
[numpy to txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0143.png)
[txt to csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryYTN.png)

this is my numpy to txt code

```
np.savetxt('./weight.txt', weight, fmt='%s' , delimiter=',')
```

Comment: What is `print (weight[:3])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
all_weights = np.zeros(0)
for layer_w in model.get_weights():
    all_weights = np.append(all_weights, layer_w.reshape(-1))
np.savetxt("weight.csv", all_weights, delimiter=",")
```

From [docs](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/):

> get_weights(): returns the weights of the layer as a list of Numpy
>   arrays.

For each layer in the model, you get a numpy array of different dimensions based on the layer type. You will have to collect all the weight and flatten them so that they all become one big column.

Equivalent Oneliner:

```
np.savetxt("weight.csv", 
           np.concatenate(list(map(lambda x: x.reshape(-1), model.get_weights())), axis=0 ),
           delimiter=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel associates different meaning to the comma in different countries. So you can either set the comma as cell-separator in your excel settings or save your data in a tab-separated-values-format, i.e. set sep='\t' in your code:

```
my_data.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t')
```